# Azure Data factory to SQL server in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory (ADF) and would like to know whether it is technically possible to use ADF to copy data from a source in **AWS** (not Azure) environment and put it to a sink in another **AWS** environment. I am aware that we need Integration Runtime (IR) to connect to the source. Can we achive copying to AWS as well using IR?

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-data-movement-activities#supported-data-stores-and-formats)

Data stores with * **can be on-premises or on Azure IaaS**, and require you to install Data Management Gateway on an on-premises/Azure IaaS machine.

But this does not say that we can/cannot transfer to AWS environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing ADF V1 doc. You could reference [ADF V2 doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) for ADF V2 support more data store.

Currently, ADF V2 support [Amazon Marketplace Web Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-marketplace-web-service) as Source, but not sink. But you could take a look of [generic ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odbc) if you have odbc driver for your aws sql server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My actual question is, I have an understanding that ADF cannot run outside Azure Iaas. Which means we cannot configure ADF to run on AWS or Google cloud environment. Am I right in my understanding? So to continue, even if we can transfer data between different cloud environments, ADF is very native to Azure and needs Azure environment to function. Please validate my understanding.

Comment: If you installed a selfhosted IR, then the copy job will run on the selfhosted IR. So ADF could run outside of Azure

Comment: Thanks again. I am little confused here. Is it true that ADF and IR are 2 different things? IR is used by ADF as a data management gateway. Is my statement right? When I have to move data from SQL server in AWS to another SQL server in another AWS infra, where will the ADF be configured on? I dont think it is a separate installable. Please provide a little more clarity on this.

Comment: BTW, I am aware that I can use AWS native services to copy/move data but I would like to know whether ADF can be used or not.

Comment: The Integration Runtime (IR) is the compute infrastructure used by Azure Data Factory to provide the following data integration capabilities across different network environments. You could reference this doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime And I think your statement is right.

Comment: In one copy activity, only one selfhosted IR will be used. You need make sure your IR could access both source and sink. If not, the copy will fail. And if you configure different selfhosted IR for source and sink, the copy will fail too.

Comment: If you are using copy activity, then ADF is used. Because your pipeline is created in a data factory.